# How to get data from json_encode?How to get respone by using AJAX?

Tags: php, json

I want to get use and its status in php from this json_encode response.How do I get it?   Request Like json_encode(array('online' => $status))

```
  {"online":[{"user":"1004","status":"Unmonitored"},
  {"user":"1005","status":"Unmonitored"},
  {"user":"1006","status":"Unmonitored"},
  {"user":"2501","status":"Unmonitored"},
  {"user":"2502","status":"Unmonitored"},
  {"user":"2503","status":"Unmonitored"},
  {"user":"2504","status":"Unmonitored"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is the function you are looking for.

```
<?php
$data = '{"online":[
    {"user":"1004","status":"Unmonitored"},
    {"user":"1005","status":"Unmonitored"},
    {"user":"1006","status":"Unmonitored"},
    {"user":"2501","status":"Unmonitored"},
    {"user":"2502","status":"Unmonitored"},
    {"user":"2503","status":"Unmonitored"},
    {"user":"2504","status":"Unmonitored"}
]}';

// json_decode produces stdClass object
$decoded_std = json_decode($data);
var_dump($decoded_std->online[0]->status); // "Unmonitored"

// json_decode produces associative array
$decoded_array = json_decode($data, true); // note the second param
var_dump($decoded_array['online'][0]['status']); // "Unmonitored"
```

Check the hosted working example here http://ideone.com/xaCx4E.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode JSON using the json_decode() function like so:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
(json_decode($json);    
?>
```

Another Example (read a specific object):

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$obj = json_decode($json); //read a specific object
print $obj->{'a'}; // 1
?>
```

**UPDATE** I see you updated your question to 'How to get response by using AJAX?'

```
          //start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                    //and pass downloaded data
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        //do what you want to do here

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 offers the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option for use with the `json_encode()` call.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php


$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

?>

Comment: According to his question, he's asking how to read that json_encode response.